# pool.query join array of data from different tables

Tags: node.js, postgresql

The question is. From the postgresql database, I get an array of data and want to link it to another table from the database, photos. As far as I understand, pool.query does not return data. Everything goes well inside, but outside, as you can see, the array remains empty.

And I need to collect all this data together and send it to the client.

```
router.get('/all', async (request, response) => {
await pool.query(`SELECT * FROM app_advert LEFT JOIN public.users USING (id) ORDER BY username`, async (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
      throw error;
    }
    let adverts = [];
    await results.rows.map(async advert => {
      pool
        .query(`SELECT name FROM app_advert_attachment LEFT JOIN file ON file.id=fk_file_id WHERE fk_advert_id=${advert.id}`)
        .then(res => {
          const images = res.rows[0];
          adverts = [...adverts, {...advert, images}];
        })
        .finally(() => {
          return response.status(201).json(adverts);
        });
    });
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this work...

```
router.get('/all', async (request, response) => {
    await pool.query(`SELECT * FROM app_advert LEFT JOIN public.users USING (id) ORDER BY username`, async (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
        throw error;
        }else{
            let adverts = [];
            let array = results.rows;
            array.forEach(function(item) {   
                pool.query(`SELECT name FROM app_advert_attachment LEFT JOIN file ON file.id=fk_file_id WHERE fk_advert_id=${advert.id}`)
                .then(res => {
                    // you process
                });
            })
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Yes thank you. Only I used a for loop. Not much tired and confused myself. and yet thanks for the hint